# How do I send current page no to onChange in Pagination fo material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Pagination
      count={pageCount}
      color="primary"
      onChange={() => props.onPageChange()}
 />
```

I am trying to send the current page number to onChange.

Answer (score 7):

You should use it like this:

```
onChange={props.onPageChange}
```

and the onChange function should look like this:

```
onPageChange = (event, value)
```

Value parameter is the number of your current page that is exposed as an argument of this function by the Pagination component itself.
See this code sendbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bn7nw?file=/demo.js